# Undefinded $_GET[' ...'] index

Tags: php, javascript, xml

After making a javascript variable accesable into a php file the $_GET['something'] keeps saying undefined index.

Although the proper result gets displayed and being written into the xml.

If i try to initialise it my score no longer shows up for some reason.

How can i initalise this without it showing anything at al on my screen?

Regards.

Comment: JavaScript is not the same thing as Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do  this with javascript:

```
window.location.href="index.php?scoreresult="+score
```

you have to access the variable in PHP using

```
$_GET['scoreresult']
```

instead of

```
$_GET['score']
```

If you make use of XSL to transform the XML, [XSLT::setParameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php) may be interesting to you. It allows you to register (PHP)-variables for use inside a XSL-stylesheet.

Comment: Ive made it more or less work i think. But the problem is it keeps saying the $_GET[''] is undefined in my php block.
I get this undefined message all the way until i get my results properly displayed. How can i initialise this to something 'standard'? Regards

Comment: To get a initial value use something like `$score=(isset($_GET['scoreresult']))?intval($_GET['scoreresult']):0;`

Comment: Hello thanks again for the reply. The problem is it keeps saying undefined index and it displays the score. Although the only i want is that this undefined message disapears so its not blocking any views of my game. And no mather what i put it on it keeps saying undefined until the score.php page loads at the end. Perhaps i have to put something in my index.php page ? Regards